# Include a perl variable inside a bash command in a perl script

Tags: bash, shell, perl

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
my $host = $db_conf->{host};
my @cmd = ('date',$host);
system(@cmd);
```

So the results i am expecting is:

```
Fri Aug 11 15:41:28 CST 2017 db-test-1
```

With db-test-1 being the hostname.

Here is my entire code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;
use DBI;
use Encode;
use IO::File;
use JSON;
use utf8;

BEGIN {
    binmode STDERR, ':utf8';
    binmode STDIN, ':utf8';
    binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
}

INIT {
    my @databases = </kkcorp/kksecret/db-*/db.json>;

    foreach my $filename (@databases) {
        my $fh = IO::File->new($filename, 'r') or croak $!;
        my @buf = <$fh>;
        my $str = join '', @buf;
        $fh->close;

        my $db_conf = decode_json $str;

        my $entry = int(rand(scalar(@{$db_conf})));
        $db_conf = $db_conf->[$entry]->{writer}->{params};

        my $host = $db_conf->{host};
        my $dbname = $db_conf->{dbname};
        my $password = $db_conf->{password};
        my $username = $db_conf->{username};

        my $wsrep_check = `mysql -h $host -u $username -p$password < /authdir/auto_inc_script.sql`;
$hosti
        if (index($wsrep_check, 'Value: Synced') != -1) {
            my @cmd = ('date ${host}');
            system(@cmd);
            my @wsrep_check_lines = split /\n/, $wsrep_check;
            my @table_name = grep { /Synced/ } @wsrep_check_lines;
            for my $line (@table_name){
                say STDERR $line;
            }
            say '';
        }
   }
}

__END__
```

So what i am trying to achieve in in the two statements right after the beginning of the "if" statement. The code runs fine, but ignored the ${host} variable without displaying any output for it.

Below is my results:

```
Fri Aug 11 17:13:19 CST 2017
ok        Value: Synced

Fri Aug 11 17:13:20 CST 2017
ok        Value: Synced
```

Comment: Turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;`. Check what the errors say. Post some output. Post a bit more detail, because we don't know what db_conf is. But I'd be pretty sure your `system` command is wrong, because `date localhost` errors with `invalid date`.

Comment: I have added the complete code and explained more what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your `my @cmd = ('date ${host}');` has single quotes and so `${host}` does not get interpolated.  The later `system` runs `date ${host}`. This is not what you want, right? Other than that, I don't understand from the description where the problem is ... in `mysql ..` ?

Comment: When i use double quotes instead of single, i get the error "date: invalid date..."

Comment: But what is the point of that `date ${host}`?  What is `${host}` there?  Is it supposed to be interpolated, since `$host` comes from DB? If it is, then it better had the date format that `date` command expects.  But the way you have it, you run `date` followed by a (supposed) variable `${host}` that should exist in your environment ... really?

Comment: Also note that `'...'` is one string.  So the `@cmd` array contains one element, `'date ${host}'` string (where `$`, `{`, etc are literal characters)

Comment: @zdim, the overall code is going through all db servers we host. So the reason for the $host, which by the way has been declared in the code, is to display the date on each db server as the code runs.

Comment: The `system` runs a command on the system (via shell or not, depending on its arguments).  Here you have the command to be `date`, with the argument `'${host}'`.  If you look at the man page for `date`, its argument should be a format for a date (or options), or you run it without arguments when it just prints the date.  Judged by your `mysql` command, the variable `$host` indeed has a host name.  That ain't a valid thing to pass to `date`.

Comment: What _precisely_ do you want to get from `system(@cmd)`?   If you mean to print a date followed by the host name, you can form that string in your program and then print it. You can get the timestamp with `my $t = localtime`, for instance.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is, described in my previous comment.  I posted an answer for this, please let me know if it's off.

Answer (score 0):

`system` is very powerful but also very dangerous. It is easy to make disasters, consider, if you feed it with an `rm`, better if you make absolutely clear what parameters `rm` gets before running `system`.

For this reason I always follow this practice:

1. create the commad string
2. print the command string
3. check if print representation is what i want to send to the shell
4. add the `system` part

Here is an example, from the command line:

`perl -e ' $var = "Hello"; $cmd = qq(echo $var); print "The command: $cmd \n";'`

Next, add system:

`perl -e ' $var = "Hello"; $cmd = qq(echo $var); print "the command: $cmd \n"; system($cmd);'`

Comment: I understand the dangers of system(). Anyway, when i run echo $(date) , it displays the date. But when i run your suggested command substituting the string "hello" with $(date), it does not print the date. E.g, perl -e ' $var = "$(date); $cmd = qq(echo $var); print \"The command: $cmd \n\";'

Comment: try this: `perl -e '$date = qx(date); chomp $date; $cmd=qq(echo "$date" ); print "cmd is : $cmd \n"; system($cmd);' `